# Drag and Drop files into an Excel Spreadsheet

Tags: microsoft-excel

Is there a way to drag and drop NON Excel files to cells in an Excel sheet? I'm trying to manage PDF and/or JPG files in an excel spreadsheet.

Comment: You can insert Pictures into Excel via the Insert tab but you cannot insert a PDF file. What you can insert is the link to a file on your PC.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to Superuser. Unfortunately, Excel doesn't support what you described.

As a work around, you could use the HYPERLINK function to link to files. This will keep the workbook size manageable too.

The syntax is; `HYPERLINK(link_location,friendly_name)`

You can find more information about how to use it [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/hyperlink-HP005209116.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the ridiculously fast responses! Can you think of any other platform that would allow this file storage technique?

Comment: What OS are you thinking of using? Windows or Linux, or Mac ?

Comment: It's not a spreadsheet but Evernote will let you organize pdf and jpg in a similar fashion.

Comment: Microsoft [OneNote](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/onenote/) "delivers the flexibility to gather and organize text, pictures, digital handwriting, audio and video recordings, and more — all in one digital notebook on your computer".

Comment: I'm working from Windows '07.

Comment: OneNote and EverNote are both nice tools but still dont provide the functionality I'm looking for. I need a folder to 'sit' in space on a PDF file. Basically creating a mini desk-top with a PDF background.

Answer (score 2):

I realize this is an old post, but in case someone else gets here with the same question...

You cannot drag and drop, but you CAN do exactly what the OP is asking by inserting the files as objects within the spreadsheet.

Go to the "Insert" tab

Click "Object" in the "Text" group

In the resulting dialog box, click the "Create from File" tab

Check the box that says "Display as Icon"

Browse to the file you want and select it

"Okay" your way out

Now your file will be embedded in the Excel file as a clickable icon, and it will move with the cell you put it in if you reorganize the worksheet. This works with practically any type of file, including JPEGs and PDFs. However, embedding a large number of files can make your spreadsheet file size huge.

By default, the icon will show the entire path to the file in the icon label, which can make it unreadable. You can edit this to be shorter. While still in the dialog box noted above, click the "Change Icon" button, and you will have the opportunity to edit the label. I usually just cut out all the path information and leave the original file name so I can actually read it.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 2):

Drag and drop the file first in word file. And then drag and drop the file from word to Excel.